# Unexpected kind of exception

Tags: python, exception

I am teaching basic python when I get the chance, and I wanted to show how we can easily generate each type of value, as follows:

```
>>> l = [bool,int,float,str,list,tuple,set,dict]
>>> o = [f() for f in l]
>>> o
[False, 0, 0.0, '', [], (), set([]), {}]
```

And then I thought to myself if I could add a `None` item somehow to the list, so I did this, and I got the unexpected exception:

```
>>> o = [f() for f in l, None]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here, due to combining list comprehension with another value, I expected at most a `SyntaxError`, but for some reason I got that `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Why did I get this error? What order of evaluation would cause Python to think I wanted to call a `list`?

Comment: `None` is a *value* not a type. I don't think there's an official type that you can instantiate.

Comment: You can't make a list comprehension and then also attach some other static value at the end of the list in the same expression, just separated by a comma.

Comment: *just separated by a comma* | you mean there are other ways in the same one liner?

Comment: `[... for ... in ...] + [None]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your list comp `[f() for f in l, None]` it is iterating through the iterable `l, None` or explicitly `(l, None)` which is a tuple. The item at index 0 in the tuple is l which you defined as a list so it cannot be called as `f()`

Answer (score 1):

It's because `l, None` becomes `(l, None)`.

Then after that you will be iterating and trying to call `l` as it is an element in the tuple, while you also want to call `None` which is not callable as well.

Even if only one out of a trillion throws an error, the whole code breaks.